# Find a general formula for x_k

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

The sequence $x_k$... is defined by $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 2$, and $x_{k+2} = 6x_{k+1}−13x_k$ for $k≥0$. Find a general formula for $x_k$.

I actually came here because I found a solution on here for a similar problem, but I do not understand the steps the answerer took to get here. If somebody could please eleborate on this and show me how to get to the answer, that would be great.

I know the solution for $x_k$ will contain complex numbers.

Comment: One usually gets a first solution using complex numbers, but the final form need not involve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the characteristic polynomial
$$x_{k+2}-6x_{k+1}+13x_k=0\\t^2-6t+13=0\\\frac{6\pm\sqrt{36-52}}{2}=3\pm2i\\x_n=A(3+2i)^n+B(3-2i)^n\\x_0=A+B=0\\x_1=3A+2Ai+3B-2Bi=2\\2=2Ai-2Bi\\1=i(A-B)\\\frac{1}{i}=A-B\\\frac{1}{i}=2A\\A=\frac{1}{2i}\\B=-\frac{1}{2i}\\x_n=\frac{1}{2i}(3+2i)^n-\frac{1}{2i}(3-2i)^n$$